# Eclipse hangs on startup, but second eclipse instance works

Tags: eclipse, pydev, startup, freeze

I use Eclipse Java EE IDE Kepler for Web Developers with pydev.

The first instance of Eclipse hangs on startup while loading a workspace.

If i start eclipse again, a coexist second instance of eclipse works fine.

I used different workspaces, the problem is independent from the used workspace.

Thanks

Comment: soo... what is the question?

Comment: How can i fix my damaged eclipse installation? I don't want start eclipse twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach would be identifying the stack you have when it hangs and then reporting a bug (probably in Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/ but it may be in PyDev: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev depending on the trace).

On http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F there's info on how to get information on a halting condition.